# Can't get my dynamic code to be interpolated correctly in rails4 embeded ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, erb, string-interpolation

I am passing a selected directory from a dropdown box and passing the directory path to a second dropdown box in a partial where I plan to have this value interpolated and run the Dir.glob command correctly to then display the available files in the directory selected.

I am having trouble getting the interpolation to work correctly.  One way is to use #{} with the variable in it.  This style works in my controller but then I have trouble passing the array of values to my partial (new to rails and still learning all you can do).

I tried erb in my partial which I think might have worked but I got an error and the list did not display:  cannot convert nil to string and it was on the interpretation of the select box value on the form post back page. method 'evaluate_media which renders 'index' as post.

Here is the partial with the ERB in it:

```
 require 'erb'
  <p>          
        <label>Select Partial Test File:</label><br />
        <label>Dir Partial Selected Path Choice: </label><%= dir_path_choice %><br />
        <%= dir_path_choice = params[:dir_list] %>
        <label>Partial Path Choice: </label><%= @dir_path_choice %><br />
        <% if dir_path_choice %>
            <% @dir = 'Dir.glob("' << @dir_path_choice << '/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map' %>
        <% else %>
        <% dir = 'Dir.glob('"/watchfolder/miniprod/hot/**/*.{mpg,mov}"').map' %>
        <% end %>   
        <label>Partial Dir: </label><%= @dir %><br />
        <% template = ERB.new dir %>
        <% @files = template.result %>
        <%= select_tag 'filepath', options_for_select(@files, @selected_filepath) %> 
</p>
```

Here is the string assignment that works but is hard coded:

```
<% @files = Dir.glob("/watchfolder/showtimevod/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map %>
<%= select_tag 'filepath', options_for_select(@files, @selected_filepath) %>
```

Here is the full partial that works with the hard code and that in display shows the two values are correct in their values:
@dir_path_choice (contains the directory path passed.
@dir (is the full Dir.glob string to be executed.)

```
  <p>          
        <label>Select Partial Test File:</label><br />
        <label>Dir Partial Selected Path Choice: </label><%= dir_path_choice %><br />
        <%= @dir_path_choice = params[:dir_list] %>
        <label>Partial Path Choice: </label><%= @dir_path_choice %><br />
        <% if @dir_path_choice %>
            <% @dir = 'Dir.glob("' << @dir_path_choice << '/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map' %>
        <% else %>
        <% @dir = 'Dir.glob('"/watchfolder/miniprod/hot/**/*.{mpg,mov}"').map' %>
        <% end %>   
        <label>Partial Dir: </label><%= @dir %><br />
        <% @files = Dir.glob("/watchfolder/showtimevod/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map %>
        <%= select_tag 'filepath', options_for_select(@files, @selected_filepath) %> 
  </p>
```

Here is the controller redering the partial with the value:

```
 def file_dir
    @dir_path_choice = params[:dir_list]
#   @files = "#{@dir}"    
#    @files = "Dir.glob(#{@dir_path_choice}/**/*.{mpg,mov}).map"   
#    render :partial => 'list_files', :collection => @files, :as :item 
    render :partial => 'list_files', :locals => {:dir_path_choice => @dir_path_choice }
  end   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'erb'
```

You don't require erb in views or partials.  erb is the default template language for rails.

In your partial, you are trying to access the params hash:

```
<%= dir_path_choice = params[:dir_list] %>
```

I didn't know you could do that, but when I tried it, I was able to access the params hash in a partial.  I don't know why that isn't working for you, but in any case that is not considered good practice.

It can be helpful to add the following line to your views/layouts/application.html.erb file:

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

That way every page will show what's in the params hash.  You can put that right before the closing body tag.  If you want, you can style the debug output with this css:

```
.debug_dump {  //rails automatically wraps the debug info in a <pre> tag with class="debug_dump"
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;

  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

…which you can put in assets/stylesheets/custom.css.

Then load the page that is giving you trouble and look at the debug info to see if `dir_list` has a value.

If there is a value for params[:dir_list], then you can try a couple of things:

1. You can try accessing @dir_path_choice directly in your partial.  Not considered good practice, either.
2. Because you did this: `:locals => {:dir_path_choice => @dir_path_choice}`, there should be a local variable available in your partial named `dir_path_choice` with your desired content.

If there isn't a value for params[:dir_list], then you have a problem with whatever form is submitting to your action.

Also, none of this ruby code:

```
    <%= dir_path_choice = params[:dir_list] %>
    <label>Partial Path Choice: </label><%= @dir_path_choice %><br />
    <% if dir_path_choice %>
        <% @dir = 'Dir.glob("' << @dir_path_choice << '/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map' %>
    <% else %>
    <% dir = 'Dir.glob('"/watchfolder/miniprod/hot/**/*.{mpg,mov}"').map' %>
    <% end %>   
    <label>Partial Dir: </label><%= @dir %><br />
    <% template = ERB.new dir %>
    <% @files = template.result %>
```

...has anything to do with generating html, and therefore it should not be in the view--it should be in the controller. In addition, when you do this:

```
template = ERB.new dir
```

the argument for ERB.new() must be a string containing erb, e.g

```
"<div><%= greeting %></div>"
```

and then you can do something like this:

```
require 'erb'

str = "<div><%= greeting %></div>"
greeting = "hello world"

my_erb = ERB.new(str)
puts my_erb.result  #=><div>hello world</div>
```

But why are you trying to do that?

Your dir variable, which as I mentioned above, needs to be erb code, is set here:

```
dir = 'Dir.glob('"/watchfolder/miniprod/hot/**/*.{mpg,mov}"').map
```

Yet that line has no erb in it.  In fact, I don't even know what that is.  If I try to match up quotes, I get:

```
dir = 'Dir.glob('    "/watchfolder/miniprod/hot/**/*.{mpg,mov}"   ').map
```

The first two single quotes create one string; the next two double quotes create another String, and then what is: `').map`?  Even if you had all your quotes matched up, a String does not even have a map() method.  You should have gotten 1,000 errors on that line.

Finally, when you post an error message, your interpretation of the error message is irrelevant: what people need to see is the EXACT error message copy and pasted, with line numbers and file names.  Rails error messages are pretty long, so you can start with the first 15 lines, and it should be quoted like this:

> Users/7stud/rails_projects/sample_app2/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:3:
>   unterminated string meets end of file
>   /Users/7stud/rails_projects/sample_app2/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:3:
>   syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end